# how to show one gridItem exactly in half of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i have a `RecyclerView` that shows inside the `fragment` with grid `Layoutmanager`. my question is how i can show one griditem exactly in half of screen ?

i want to show just 2 coloumn and they have a same height.

> this is my grid item (represent one grid item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewGridItemXml"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topLayoutGridItemXml"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTumbnailGridItemXml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtTitleGridItemXml"
                android:src="@drawable/leopard"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleGridItemXml"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#ff444444"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="Test"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> and this is My `GridLayoutManager` :

```
 GridLayoutManager  gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

[image: This my screen shot]

Comment: Krupal i dont use a gridview , i use a RecyclerView .

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but probably you would also want to give specific height to your grid item, instead of `match_parent`

Comment: krupal , i write GridlayoutManager with 2 count before

Comment: set width to match parent in your row layout instead of specifying fixed width